# What are the largest fully publicly available molecular QTL datasets?

Tags: genomics, public-dataset, qtls

I'm familiar with the sQTL and eQTL GTEx data that can be downloaded from the
[GTEx Portal](https://gtexportal.org/home/datasets), but I'm interested in gathering at least two other types of molecular QTL datasets:

1. Larger eQTL and/or sQTL datasets (greater overall sample size, even if performed only for blood cells)
2. Other functional molecular QTLs such as methylation QTLs, histone QTLs, DNA accessibility QTLs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The largest eQTL datasets I can think of is probably [eQTLGen](https://eqtlgen.org/). This is a meta-analysis of many studies using >30,000 samples from whole blood. This might be less ideal if you want cell-type-specific QTL information.

For other molecular QTLs, I do not think there are large-scale datasets yet.